# Deleting a heap allocated 2-dimensional vector

Tags: c++, memory-management, vector

So I have a vector of vectors that is heap allocated:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>>* matrix = new std::vector<std::vector<int>>();
```

After putting a considerable amount of data into `matrix`. What is the correct way to delete this object?

Does `delete matrix` deallocate all of the internal vectors?

Comment: Yes, but why are you dynamically allocating the vector in the first place? That really rarely makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes `delete matrix;` will be fine.

You may want to consider if you need to dynamically allocate your vector. Vectors always store their data on the free-store (heap) so they don't need to be dynamically allocated for that reason. They have a very small stack foot-print.

If you *must* allocate your vector dynamically then you should seriously consider using a *smart pointer* such as a [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) or a [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr), then you won't need to call `delete` at all:

```
auto matrix = std::make_unique<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>();
```

Comment: I'll address if I need to allocate the vector dynamically in another question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. `delete matrix` calls the destructor of the `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` before returning memory. The destructor call will call the destructor of all its elements, `std::vector<int>`.

Also, most usage of `std::vector` wouldn't require you to create it on the heap. I suspect the same with your case.